# Android plugin for gradle 3.0.* using Gradle's new dependency configurations compileOnly not working with resource reference

Tags: android, gradle

I have two module, `support` and `mall` which is local module for main entry module `app`.

but in module `mall`, I had reference a lot of resource in `support`.

- before android plugin for gradle 3.0:

I just used `compile` in module `mall` 's dependencies in `build.gradle` to include `support`

and I used `compile` in module `app` to include both modules `support` and `mall`.

It works find.

- after android plugin for gradle 3.0:

I wanted to upgrade [using Gradle's new dependency configurations: implementation, api, compileOnly, and runtimeOnly](https://developer.android.google.cn/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#variant_aware).

But it's not working for me when I use  compileOnly in module `mall` to include `support` dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `compile` instruction with `implementation`.
`compileOnly` instruction not changed in gradle 3.0 you shouldn't use it.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it.